# in SQLite how to implement a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am making an SQLite database that has a many to many relationship I have broken this up into two one to many relationships with the following code

```
SQLiteManager: CREATE  TABLE "main"."LESSONS" 
(
   "LESSONID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  
   NOT NULL , "MODULEID" INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(MODULEID) REFERENCES MODULES 
   (MODULEID), "STUDENTID" INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (STUDENITD) REFERENCES STUDENTS
   (STUDENTID)
)
```

Error:

```
[near ""STUDENTID"": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
[mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

does anyone know how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html); it’ll show you that if you specify a foreign key on the field definition itself, you shouldn’t use the keyword `FOREIGN KEY` itself.  Also, you used too many commas, as pointed out by **CL.**, and even when specifying the constraint separately, the foreign key name should not be in parentheses.

This statement does what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE "LESSONS"
(
    "LESSONID"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "MODULEID"  INTEGER REFERENCES MODULES(MODULEID),
    "STUDENTID" INTEGER REFERENCES STUDENTS(STUDENTID)
);
```

Also note that, if MODULEID is the primary key of table MODULES, then you don’t have to specify it, per se; SQLite doesn’t require it. That being said, I prefer specifying it like this since other SQL engines do expect it.

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo error on declaring the `foreign key`

```
FOREIGN KEY (STUDENITD)
```

should be

```
FOREIGN KEY (STUDENTID)
```

Comment: Thanks for notifying me of the typo. Sorry about that, but after changing it, it's still not working :/

Answer (score 2):

You have too many commas.
Column attributes are not separated by commas; use them only between table columns:

```
CREATE  TABLE "LESSONS" 
(
    "LESSONID"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "MODULEID"  INTEGER FOREIGN KEY (MODULEID)  REFERENCES MODULES(MODULEID),
    "STUDENTID" INTEGER FOREIGN KEY (STUDENTID) REFERENCES STUDENTS(STUDENTID)
)
```

Comment: This one is still not correct: the foreign key name should not be in parentheses.  Also, you're naming the foreign key after the field name, which is not good practice.

Comment: ...and finally, when defining a foreign key inline, you must omit the `FOREIGN KEY constraint-name` part, and just specify `REFERENCES table(field)`.