# Multiple unique columns sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm working on a web application which has to do with restaurant menu. I'm using node for back-end and sqlite3 for database system. In my 'items' table i have a field called barcode which is of-course unique, but the user can input some "extra barcodes". What i need is a way to make barcode field and extra_barcodes fields unique between each others.

Comment: What does "unique between each others" mean? Provide a mathematical definition, or show some examples.

Comment: In example : if item has barcode "a1" ALL items should not be able to have barcode OR extra_barcode "a1" .

Comment: Could you use a table called barcodes that contains the barcodes? The items table barcode field would be a foreign key from barcode. If the user could add several 'extra barcodes' then a secondary table to implement a many-to-many relationship. An example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227468/in-sqlite-how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship).

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating another table, although i think there is no other way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the same value occurring in multiple columns, you cannot use CHECK constraints (because subqueries are not allowed there), so you have to use triggers:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER barcode_unique_insert
AFTER INSERT ON items
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "duplicate barcode")
    FROM items
    WHERE extra_barcode  = NEW.barcode
       OR extra2_barcode = NEW.barcode;
END;
```

It might be a better idea to store barcodes in a separate table with an 1:N relationship.